# Javascript while setTimeout

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout, greasemonkey

I want to make a GreaseMonkey script. I want to have a `setTimeout` at the end of my while, but I don't know how to do that.

```
run();
function run(){
  var klovas = document.getElementById("light").innerHTML;
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("farm_icon farm_icon_a");
  if(klovas < 6){
    alert("Kevés egység van");
  } else {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < btn.length){
      if(typeof btn[i] != "undefined"){
        btn[i].click();
      }
    i++;
    setTimeout("run()", 3000);
    }
  }
}
```

With this code, the problem is that the `setTimeout` is not working and doesn't wait 3 seconds like it is supposed to.

I tried other ways, but nothing has worked.

**EDIT**

```
function run(){
  var klovas = document.getElementById("light").innerHTML;
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("farm_icon farm_icon_a");
  if(klovas < 2){
    alert("Kevés egység van");
  } else {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < btn.length){
      if(typeof btn[i] != "undefined"){
        btn[i].click();
      }
    i++;    
    }
  }
}
setInterval(run, 6000);
```

I tryed this. Its runing every 6 sec, but i get error in website, that i cand click more than 5 times in a sec. So waiting 6secound when i open the page, and after click, and i get error. Its not jet working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted it to only trigger once:

```js
function run(){
    var data = [1,2,3];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < data.length) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

setTimeout(run, 3000);
```

The way you wrote it now, it would repeat every 3 seconds.

```js
function run(){
    var data = [1,2,3];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < data.length) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    setTimeout(run, 3000);
}

run();
```

But setInterval would accomplish the same results.

```js
function run(){
    var data = [1,2,3];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < data.length) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

setInterval(run, 3000);
```

**EDIT**

User wanted to see what would happen if you call setInterval from inside the callback function.  Note that the number of intervals grows exponentially every 3 seconds.

setInterval causes the function to run **every** 3 seconds, while setTimeout causes the function to run **once** in 3 seconds.

```js
var numberOfIntervals = 0;

function run(){
    setInterval(run, 3000);
    numberOfIntervals++;
    console.log(numberOfIntervals);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

Firstly, while setTimeout can accept a function as its first argument, you would want to pass the function as an argument, not execute the function, so you should replace `"run()"` with `run`.

Secondly, I'm not exactly sure why you're recursing -- why is `setTimeout` inside `run()`? Instead of putting it inside your run function, try putting it at the bottom, and deleting the `run()` call at the top. As far as I can tell, there's no reason that this code needs to recurse at alll.

Comment: @Xufox My mistake! I'll edit that right now.

Comment: I need a break after i++. Now i tryed to alert the btn[i], and when i get up the alert, and i press ok, then working good. just i must always press ok. :D
function run(){
  var klovas = document.getElementById("light").innerHTML;
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("farm_icon farm_icon_a");
  if(klovas < 2){
    alert("Not enought light");
  } else {
    var i = 1;
    while(i < btn.length){
     btn[i].click();
     i++;
     alert(btn[i]);
    }
  }
}
setInterval(run, 5000);

Like this